# How to change text field value automatically in JSP?

Tags: jsp

I have 2 text fields in my page with `id="textfield1"` and `id="textfield2"`:

```
<input type="text" name="textfield1" id="textfield1" size="70" />
<input type="text" name="textfield1" id="textfield2" size="70" />
```

If I change `textfield1`, then I want to change `textfield2` value automatically in JSP.

Comment: it should be done in javascript as changing text value, is happening in browser(which is after all jsp processing is complete and html generated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this javascript function

```
function changeVal() 
{ 
document.getElementById("textfield2").value="abc";   
}
```

call this on blur event of textbox1

```
<input type="text" name="textfield1" id="textfield1" size="70" onkeyleave="changeVal()"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use small javascript code as below:

```
function fillTextbox(){
var tf1=document.getElementById("textfield1").value;
document.getElementById("textfield2").value=tf1;
}


<input type="text" name="textfield1" id="textfield1" size="70" onkeyleave="fillTextbox()" />

<input type="text" name="textfield1" id="textfield2" size="70" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Write onchange function like this:

```
$('#textfield1').change(function() {
$('#textfield2').val($('#textfield1').val());
});
```

Comment: This relies on JQuery, do we know if the OP is using it?

Comment: @JohnFarrelly:Writing the stuff in jquery reduces the writing of lengthy java script code.

Comment: I definitely agree, but the OP needs to know to include JQuery to make the code above work.

Comment: @JohnFarrelly:Good point,i should i have asked it first or should have given javascript solution.thanks john..... :)